# Which is the maximum number of combinations between two populations

Tags: combinatorics

I have two populations of size N1 and N2:

pop1 = {a,b,c,d,e,f,g} and
pop2 = {h,i,j,k,l}

I want to produce combinations of this two populations swapping individuals between the two but keeping the same population sizes.
Which is the number of unique new populations I can create?

Comment: This reads somewhat like a routine textbook-style question. Is this a question for a class?

Comment: The time of class questionaries is long gone for me. Sorry if the question was too simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you talking about permutations (in which the order matters) or combinations (in which the order doesn't matter)? You say permutations, but you talk about unique populations so I assume that you mean combinations.

Let n be the number of unique individuals and k be the size of one of the categories (it doesn't matter if you use N1 or N2):

$$ \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} $$